# Ruby c extensions: How can I catch all exceptions, including things that aren't StandardErrors?

Tags: c, ruby, exception, ruby-c-extension, rescue

In ruby,

```
begin
  # ...
rescue
  # ...
end
```

won't catch exceptions that aren't subclasses of `StandardError`. In C,

```
rb_rescue(x, Qnil, y, Qnil);

VALUE x(void) { /* ... */ return Qnil; }
VALUE y(void) { /* ... */ return Qnil; }
```

will do the same thing. How can I `rescue Exception => e` from a ruby C extension (instead of just `rescue => e`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby needs more documentation. I had to go into the ruby source code, and this is what I found:

```
VALUE
rb_rescue(VALUE (* b_proc)(ANYARGS), VALUE data1,
      VALUE (* r_proc)(ANYARGS), VALUE data2)
{
    return rb_rescue2(b_proc, data1, r_proc, data2, rb_eStandardError,
              (VALUE)0);
}
```

So, the answer to my question (i guess) would be:

```
rb_rescue2(x, Qnil, y, Qnil, rb_eException, (VALUE)0);

VALUE x(void) { /* ... */ return Qnil; }
VALUE y(void) { /* ... */ return Qnil; }
```

Comment: +1 Just hit the same problem and this discovery resolved my problem.

Comment: I would vote this up, but am not clear on what callbacks do what. What gets called in the event of a rescue? What is being rescued?

Comment: I would assume `b_proc` is the code after the `begin` statement, and `r_proc` is the rescue code.